# How to use udev rules to management /dev/xxx when running in container

Tags: systemd, udev, docker

Firstly I want say , I am not really want to modify /dev/random 's access in product , This is just a test to verify when systemd running in moby  , udev 's rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/xxxx 's behavior

Question1:  why only when use --priviledged container, container's udev management rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/xxx  is valid ?

what authority systemd need if systemd need to use udev to manage /dev/xxx by /etc/udev/rules.d/xxx ?

Question2:  when I start a container  use --priviledged, why container restart will modify phycalhost's /dev/xxx access and use physicalhost's  /etc/udev/rules.d/xxx  rules? I think this is not reasonable

#### Used distribution

redhat 7.2

#### In case of bug report: Steps to reproduce the problem

### start a containerA with no --priviledged

```
[root@physicalhost /home/ahao.mah]
#docker run -d --net host reg.docker.xxxxx.com/mybase/centos7u2:latest
36cc8f6759294b2b2900b313c4f978737b11671b7ab2cc185e69fba3f6a9d10c

[root@containerA /home/ahao.mah]
#docker exec -it 36cc8f6759294b2b2900b313c4f978737b11671b7ab2cc185e69fba3f6a9d10c bash
```

modify udev rules  in containerA :

```
[root@containerA /]
#cat  /etc/udev/rules.d/70-test_random.rules
KERNEL=="random",  GROUP="root", MODE="0665", OPTIONS="last_rule"
```

restart this containerA:

```
[root@physicalhost /home/ahao.mah]
#docker restart 36cc8f675929
36cc8f675929
```

containerA's  /dev/random still 0666 ,but not 0665

```
[root@containerA /]
#ll /dev/random
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 8 Aug  8 11:34 /dev/random
```

At this moment I do not know  why /etc/udev/rules.d/xxx rules is invalid in a no --priviledges container?

### start a containerB with --priviledge

```
[root@physicalhost /home/ahao.mah]
#docker run -d --net host --privileged reg.docker.xxxxx.com/mybase/centos7u2:latest

[root@containerB /home/ahao.mah]
#docker exec -it 1853437e8d2ea7018475b2328a10f1625da8b0c667941d69d912598325dc830d bash
```

Now containerB's /dev/random default access  is also 0666,but I want to modify containerB's /dev/random access to 0660, then I need to use udev rules in /etc/udev/rules.d/xxx

```
[root@containerB /]
#ll /dev/random
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 8 Aug  8 11:40 /dev/random

[root@containerB /]
#vim /etc/udev/rules.d/70-test_random.rules
KERNEL=="random",  GROUP="root", MODE="0660", OPTIONS="last_rule"
```

Now physicalhost's /dev/random default access  is also 0666,but I modify physical's /dev/random access to 0777

```
[root@physicalhost /]
#cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-test_random.rules
#KERNEL=="random",  GROUP="root", MODE="0777", OPTIONS="last_rule"

[root@physicalhost /]
#ll /dev/random
#crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 8 Aug  8 11:40 /dev/random
```

restart containerB:

```
[root@physicalhost /home/ahao.mah]
#docker restart 1853437e8d2e
1853437e8d2e
```

both containerB's /dev/random and physicalhost's /dev/access is changed!

```
[root@containerB /]
#ll /dev/random
crw-rw---- 1 root root 1, 8 Aug  8 11:41 /dev/random

[root@physicalhost /home/ahao.mah]
#ll /dev/random
crwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1, 8 Aug  8 11:43 /dev/random
```

My views:

1. I think this relate to systemd running in docker  priv
2. when running with --priviledges , systemd running in docker should not modify physicalhost's /dev/xxx access by /etc/udev/rules.d/xxx
3. when running with no --priviledges , systemd running in docker should can  modify container's /dev/xxx access by /etc/udev/rules.d/xxx

Answer (score 1):

I got my solution ,when a containerA created by  --privileged , this containerA have /sys rw access , and service systemd-udev-trigger.serivce can be excuted success. this means udevadm can trigger uevent to /sys/devices/*/*/uevent and physical host also can get this uevent, then physical use it's /etc/udev/rules.d/xxx

the point of udevadm trigger is to tell the kernel to send events for all the devices that are present. It does that by writing to /sys/devices/*/*/uevent. This requires sysfs to be mounted read-write on /sys。