# should systemd-udev-trigger be masked in container?

Tags: systemd, udev, docker

I asked this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384668/how-to-use-udev-rules-to-management-dev-xxx-when-running-in-container)  I think  systemd-udev-trigger  should not be execute in docker container , whatever it is --privileged or not .

Is there some scenes must need excute systemd-udev-trigger in docker container?

Answer (score 0):

The first, least specific answer to this is that systemd-udev is not designed to run inside containers.  And that Docker is not quite intended to run systemd inside it, only a single daemon.

The container image you mentioned does have instructions for running systemd.  They involve removing the udev services that would run inside an unprivileged container.  This is valid inside a Docker container because you're never supposed to use the package manager after the build process.

In a privileged container, I think these instructions should also be sufficient to disable udev.  On my Fedora 26 system, it's a static want of `sysinit.target`.  Notice how the code removes all static wants of `sysinit.target`, except for `systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service`.

> ## Systemd integration
>
> Systemd is now included in both the centos:7 and centos:latest base
>   containers, but it is not active by default. In order to use systemd,
>   you will need to include text similar to the example Dockerfile below:
>
> ### Dockerfile for systemd base image
>
> `dockerfile FROM centos:7 ENV container docker RUN (cd
>   /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
>   systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \ rm -f
>   /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\ rm -f
>   /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\ rm -f
>   /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \ rm -f
>   /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \ rm -f
>   /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \ rm -f
>   /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\ rm -f
>   /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*; VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup"
>   ] CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]`
>
> This Dockerfile deletes a number of unit files which might cause
>   issues. From here, you are ready to build your base image.
>
> `console $ docker build --rm -t local/c7-systemd .`
>
> ### Example systemd enabled app container
>
> In order to use the systemd enabled base container created above, you
>   will need to create your `Dockerfile` similar to the one below.
>
> `dockerfile FROM local/c7-systemd RUN yum -y install httpd; yum
>   clean all; systemctl enable httpd.service EXPOSE 80 CMD
>   ["/usr/sbin/init"]`
>
> Build this image:
>
> `console $ docker build --rm -t local/c7-systemd-httpd .`
>
> ### Running a systemd enabled app container
>
> In order to run a container with systemd, you will need to mount the
>   cgroups volumes from the host. Below is an example command that will
>   run the systemd enabled httpd container created earlier.
>
> `console $ docker run -ti -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -p
>   80:80 local/c7-systemd-httpd`
>
> This container is running with systemd in a limited context, with the
>   cgroups filesystem mounted. There have been reports that if you're
>   using an Ubuntu host, you will need to add `-v /tmp/$(mktemp -d):/run`
>   in addition to the cgroups mount.